# Warning : Data size is larger than global or bulk size

Tags: arrays, c, size

I have a C code that includes an array with values, serving as a kind of lookup table.

When I try to compile this C code, I get the error "warning: data size is larger than global or bulk size" while creating the lookup table. Similarly, I encounter the same error when compiling the main code. What could be the rea son for this? Can you please guide me on the steps I should follow?

Here is my result : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9X9l.png)

In addition, I need to mention that this lookup table was compiling successfully before making changes. However, when I modify some values, it starts giving this error. Yet, when I compare the sizes before and after the changes, the dimensions remain the same. There must be a different issue causing this error.

Here is a little part of my code,  it continues like this, totaling 2100 lines, so I can't share all of them.

```
#include "suc.h"
ML101C ml101c_g[6] = {
/***************************************************************** 
*** Case 1
*****************************************************************/
/* pdi information data */
/* upper limit */
1510,           /* entry thickness      [0.001mm]       */
1350,           /* strip width          [mm]            */
1510,           /* delivery thickness   [0.001mm]       */
900 ,           /* steel grade code     [-]             */
99,             /* shape pattern    [-]                 */
1500,           /* ent. thick. diff.    [0.001mm]       */
0,              /* spare                                */
0,              /* spare                                */
/* lower limit */
150,            /* entry thickness      [0.001mm]       */
680,            /* strip width          [mm]            */
110,            /* delivery thickness   [0.001mm]       */
1,              /* steel grade code     [-]             */
1,              /* shape pattern    [-]                 */
0,              /* ent. thick. diff.    [0.01mm]        */
0,              /* spare                                */
0,              /* spare                                */

/* mill operation information data */
/* upper limit */
1500,                   /* Roll speed           [mpm]           */
1500,                   /* Roll speed           [mpm]           */
1500,                   /* Roll speed           [mpm]           */
1500,                   /* Roll speed           [mpm]           */
1500,                   /* strip speed          [mpm]           */
1500,                   /* strip speed          [mpm]           */
1500,                   /* strip speed          [mpm]           */
5000,                   /* #1 forward slip      [10 2]          */
5000,                   /* #2 forward slip      [10 2]          */
9999,                   /* #1 elongation        [%]             */
9999,                   /* #2 elongation        [%]             */
 300,                   /* Roll gap FGC DS                      */
 300,                   /* Roll gap FGC DS                      */
 800,                   /* entry thickness      [mm]            */
 800,                   /* #1 delivery thickness[mm]            */
 800,                   /* #2 delivery thickness[mm]            */
 500,                   /* #1 draft rate        [0.1%]          */
 500,                   /* #2 draft rate        [0.1%]          */
30000,                  /* Roll force #1        [kN]            */
30000,                  /* Roll force #2        [kN]            */
2800,                   /* POR-ETB unit tension [kg/mm2]        */
2800,                   /* ETB-#1 unit tension  [kg/mm2]        */
2800,                   /* #1-#2 unit tension   [kg/mm2]        */
2800,                   /* #2-DTB unit tension  [kg/mm2]        */
2800,                   /* DTB-TR unit tension  [kg/mm2]        */
 300,                   /* POR-ETB total tension[0.1kN]         */
 490,                   /* ETB-#1 total tension [0.1kN]         */
 970,                   /* #1-#2 total tension  [0.1kN]         */
 800,                   /* #2-DTB total tension [0.1kN]         */
 350,                   /* DTB-TR total tension [0.1kN]         */
 190,                   /* #1 wr bender         [0.1MPa]        */
 190,                   /* #2 wr bender         [0.1MPa]        */
 190,                   /* #1 imr bender        [0.1MPa]        */
 190,                   /* #2 imr bender        [0.1MPa]        */
 250,                   /* #1 imr shift         [mm]            */
 250,                   /* #2 imr shift         [mm]            */
1500,                   /* motor power balance #1/#2            */
1500,                   /* motor power balance #1/#2            */
  20,                   /* taper pattern number                 */
 999,                   /* Init  total tension  [kg/mm2]        */
 999,                   /* taper end point      [-]             */
  99,                   /* shape pattern        [-]             */
1500,                   /* motor power balance #1/#2            */
1500,                   /* POR                                  */
 750,                   /* ETB                                  */
3000,                   /* #1stand                              */
1500,                   /* #2stand                              */
 950,                   /* DTB                                  */
1500,                   /* TR                                   */

/* setup information data */
/* upper limit */
1.4000e+0,      /* #1 zp        [-]         */ 
2.0000e+0,      /* #2 zp        [-]         */
/* lower limit */
0.5000e+0,      /* #1 zp        [-]         */ 
0.5000e+0,      /* #2 zp        [-]         */ 
/* upper limit */
5.0000e+0,      /* #1 delta s0      [mm]        */
5.0000e+0,      /* #2 delta s0      [mm]        */
/* lower limit */
-5.0000e+0,     /* #1 delta s0      [mm]        */
-5.0000e+0,     /* #2 delta s0      [mm]        */
/* upper limit */
1.5000e+0,      /* #1 zt        [-]         */
1.5000e+0,      /* #2 zt        [-]         */
/* lower limit */
0.7000e+0,      /* #1 zt        [-]         */
0.7000e+0,      /* #2 zt        [-]         */
/* upper limit */
1.0000e+1,      /* #1 zsr       [-]         */
1.0000e+1,      /* #2 zsr       [-]         */
/* lower limit */
0.2000e+0,      /* #1 zsr       [-]         */
0.2000e+0,      /* #2 zsr       [-]         */
/* upper limit */
1.1500e+0,      /* #1 zf        [-]         */
1.1500e+0,      /* #2 zf        [-]         */
/* lower limit */
0.9000e+0,      /* #1 zf        [-]         */
0.9000e+0,      /* #2 zf        [-]         */
/* upper limit */
1.5000e+0,      /* Spare            [-]         */
1.5000e+0,      /* Spare            [-]         */
1.5000e+0,      /* Spare            [-]         */
/* lower limit */
0.5000e+0,      /* spare        [-]         */
0.5000e+0,      /* spare        [-]         */
0.5000e+0,      /* spare        [-]         */
/* upper limit */
0.7000e+0,      /* #1 sr        [-]         */
0.7000e+0,      /* #2 sr        [-]         */
/* lower limit */
0.0050e+0,      /* #1 sr        [-]         */ 
0.0050e+0,      /* #2 sr        [-]         */ 
/* upper limit */
3.0700e+3,      /* POR-ETB total tension[kg]        */
5.0000e+3,      /* ETB-#1 total tension [kg]        */
9.9000e+3,      /* #1-#2 total tension  [kg]        */
8.1700e+3,      /* #2-DTB total tension [kg]        */
3.5700e+3,      /* DTB-TR total tension [kg]        */
/* lower limit */
3.0000e+2,      /* POR-ETB total tension[kg]        */
5.0000e+2,      /* ETB-#1 total tension [kg]        */
1.4000e+3,      /* #1-#2 total tension  [kg]        */
7.0000e+2,      /* #2-DTB total tension [kg]        */
3.9000e+2,      /* DTB-TR total tension [kg]        */
/* upper limit */
0.2500e+0,      /* #1 forward slip      [-]         */
0.0500e+0,      /* #2 forward slip  [-]         */
/* lower limit */
-0.0100e+0,     /* #1 forward slip      [-]         */
-0.0100e+0,     /* #2 forward slip  [-]         */
/* upper limit */
1.5000e+3,      /* #1 roll speed    [mpm]       */
1.5000e+3,      /* #2 roll speed    [mpm]       */
/* lower limit */
1.0000e+0,      /* #1 roll speed    [mpm]       */
1.0000e+0,      /* #2 roll speed    [mpm]       */
/* upper limit */
1.6100e+3,      /* #1 contact length    [mm]        */
1.6100e+3,      /* #2 contact length    [mm]        */
/* lower limit */
4.0000e+2,      /* #1 contact length    [mm]        */
4.0000e+2,      /* #2 contact length    [mm]        */
/* upper limit */
1.6100e+3,      /* #1 contact length    [mm]        */
1.6100e+3,      /* #2 contact length    [mm]        */
/* lower limit */
4.0000e+2,      /* #1 contact length    [mm]        */
4.0000e+2,      /* #2 contact length    [mm]        */
/* upper limit */
1.2750e+3,      /* #1 roll revolution   [rpm]       */
1.1650e+3,      /* #2 roll revolution   [rpm]       */
/* lower limit */
0.5000e+2,      /* #1 roll revolution   [rpm]       */
0.5000e+2,      /* #2 roll revolution   [rpm]       */
/* upper limit */
1.1849e+3,      /* #1 motor current [A]         */
0.5760e+3,      /* #2 motor current [A]         */
/* lower limit */
-1.2160e+3,     /* #1 motor current [A]         */
-1.2610e+3,     /* #2 motor current [A]         */
/* upper limit (bright roll)*/
0.0680e+0,              /* #1 friction coefficient      [-]     */
0.0500e+0,              /* #2 friction coefficient      [-]     */
/* upper limit (dull roll)*/
0.2000e+0,              /* #1 friction coefficient      [-]     */
0.1500e+0,              /* #2 friction coefficient      [-]     */
/* lower limit (bright roll)*/
0.0100e+0,              /* #1 friction coefficient      [-]     */
0.0100e+0,              /* #2 friction coefficient      [-]     */
/* lower limit (dull roll)*/
0.0500e+0,              /* #1 friction coefficient      [-]     */
0.0500e+0,              /* #2 friction coefficient      [-]     */
/* upper limit */
1.2000e+0,      /* roll force compensation  [-]     */
1.2000e+0,      /* forward slip compensation    [-]     */
0.0e+0,         /* spare                */
0.0e+0,         /* spare                */
0.0e+0,         /* spare                */
/* lower limit */
0.8000e+0,      /* roll force compensation  [-]     */
0.8000e+0,      /* forward slip compensation    [-]     */
0.0e+0,         /* spare                */
0.0e+0,         /* spare                */
0.0e+0,         /* spare                */
/* upper limit */
1370,           /* Splash gaurd max width   [mm]    */
/* lower limit */
500,            /* Splash gaurd min width   [mm]    */
/* upper limit */
1.5000e+3,      /* mill delivery max speed  [mpm]           (maxspd)*/
2.5000e+2,      /* mill delivery max speed(FGC) [mpm]       (maxfgc)*/
/* lower limit */
1.0000e+2,      /* mill delivery min speed(FGC) [mpm]   */
/*       limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 speed cone ratio  [-]         */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 speed cone ratio  [-]         */
/*       limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 plastic coefficient para  [-]     */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 plastic coefficient para  [-]     */
/* upper limit */
4.2030e+3,      /* #1 horse power   [HP] */
2.0115e+3,      /* #2 horse power   [HP] */
/* lower limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 horse power   [HP]        */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 horse power   [HP]        */
/*       limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 power ratio   [-]         */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 power ratio   [-]         */
/* upper limit */
1.9000e+1,      /* #1 wr bender     [0.1MPa]    */
1.9000e+1,      /* #2 wr bender     [0.1MPa]    */
/* lower limit */
-1.9000e+1,     /* #1 wr bender     [0.1MPa]    */
-1.9000e+1,     /* #2 wr bender     [0.1MPa]    */
/* upper limit */
1.9000e+1,      /* #1 imr bender    [0.1MPa]    */
1.9000e+1,      /* #2 imr bender    [0.1MPa]    */
/* lower limit */
3.0000e+0,      /* #1 imr bender    [0.1MPa]    */
3.0000e+0,      /* #2 imr bender    [0.1MPa]    */
/* upper limit */
3.2700e+4,      /* #1 entry plastic coefficient [kg/mm] */
3.2700e+4,      /* #2 entry plastic coefficient [kg/mm] */
/* lower limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 entry plastic coefficient [kg/mm] */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 entry plastic coefficient [kg/mm] */
/* upper limit */
3.2700e+4,      /* #1 del. plastic coefficient  [kg/mm] */
3.2700e+4,      /* #2 del. plastic coefficient  [kg/mm] */
/* lower limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 del. plastic coefficient  [kg/mm] */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 del. plastic coefficient  [kg/mm] */
/* upper limit */
3.2700e+4,      /* #1 acc/dec gain  [kg]        */
3.2700e+4,      /* #2 acc/dec gain  [kg]        */
/* lower limit */
0.0000e+0,      /* #1 acc/dec gain  [kg]        */
0.0000e+0,      /* #2 acc/dec gain  [kg]        */
/* upper limit */
4.9000e+2,      /* #1 hc-delta      [mm]        */
4.9000e+2,      /* #2 hc-delta      [mm]        */
/* lower limit */
-4.2300e+2,     /* #1 hc-delta      [mm]        */
-4.2300e+2,     /* #2 hc-delta      [mm]        */
/* upper limit */
3.5000e+3,      /*taper initial tension [kg]     uit   */
/* upper limit */
5.0000e+1,      /* max width deviation  [mm]        */
/* lower limit */
0e+1,           /* min width deviation  [mm]        */
/* upper limit */
2.7500e+3,      /* #1 rolling force [ton]       */
2.7500e+3,      /* #2 rolling force [ton]       */
/* lower limit */
1.0000e+1,      /* #1 rolling force [ton]       */
1.0000e+1,      /* #2 rolling force [ton]       */
/* upper limit */
1.5000e+0,      /* motor power balance #1/#2 std      */
/* lower limit */
0.5000e+0,      /* motor power balance #1/#2 std      */
/* upper limit */
4.9000e+2,              /* #1 WR shift          [mm]            */
4.9000e+2,              /* #2 WR shift          [mm]            */
/* lower limit */
-4.2300e+2,             /* #1 WR shift          [mm]            */
-4.2300e+2,             /* #2 WR shift          [mm]            */
/* upper limit */
1.0000e+2,              /* #1 level             [-]             */
1.0000e+2,              /* #2 level             [-]             */
/* lower limit */
-1.0000e+2,             /* #1 level             [-]             */
-1.0000e+2,             /* #2 level             [-]             */
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,
/* lot change limit */
1.0000e+0,      /* ent. thick. diff.    [mm]        */
3.0000e+1,      /* strip width      [mm]        */
0.1000e+0,      /* #5 delivery thickness[mm]        */
1.0000e+0,      /* mill entry thickness [mm]        */
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What target hardware are you building for? Is it some microcontroller with rather limited resources? Or maybe with a non-linear memory addressing model?

Comment: My ***guess*** is that you're building for a small embedded system which just doesn't have enough memory to fit the array.

Comment: [Edit] and show the array. How large is it? Or even better show a [mcve].

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your **code**.. The picture of the compiler output is not helpful. Also don't show pictures of text, instead show text as properly formatted text.